# RedirectToAction after callback in ASP.NET MVC

Tags: c#, asp.net, asp.net-mvc, redirecttoaction

I want to redirect to action after doing some tasks (sending an email), but I can't figure-out how to do that correctly.

Here's my code, but the `RedirectToAction` aren't doing anything here!

```
[HttpPost]
public ActionResult SendEmail(EmailContentViewModel emailDetails)
{
    using (MailMessage email = new MailMessage(emailDetails.from, emailDetails.to))
    {
        email.Subject = emailDetails.subject;
        email.Body = emailDetails.body;
        email.Priority = emailDetails.MailPriority;

        processSendingEmail(email, (result) =>
        {
            RedirectToAction("ContactResult", "Contact", new { success = result }); //It's not redirecting to the ContactResult page!
        });
    }

    return null;
}
```

---

```
private void processSendingEmail(MailMessage email, Action<bool> callback= null)
    {
        using (SmtpClient smtpClient = new SmtpClient(_smtpHostName, _smtpPort))
        {
            bool sentSuccessfully = false;

            try
            {
               //.............//
            }
            catch(Exception e)
            {
               //.............//
            }

            callback?.Invoke(sentSuccessfully);
        }
    }
```

---

Based on [Panagiotis Kanavos's response](https://stackoverflow.com/a/54713219/10100062), here is a working code:

```
    [HttpPost]
    public async Task<ActionResult> SendEmail(EmailContentViewModel emailDetails)
    {
        using (MailMessage email = new MailMessage(emailDetails.from, emailDetails.to))
        {
            email.Subject = emailDetails.subject;
            email.Body = emailDetails.body;
            email.Priority = emailDetails.MailPriority;

            var sentSuccessfully= await processSendingEmail(email);

            return RedirectToAction("ContactResult", "Contact", new { success = sentSuccessfully});
        }
    }


    private async Task<bool> processSendingEmail(MailMessage email)
    {
        var client = new MailKit.Net.Smtp.SmtpClient();
        //Configure the client here ...
        try
        {
            var msg = (MimeKit.MimeMessage)email;
            await client.SendAsync(msg);
            return true;
        }
        catch (Exception ex)
        {
            Debug.Fail(ex.Message);
            string errorMessage = "";
            switch (ex)
            {
                case SmtpFailedRecipientException f:
                    errorMessage = $"Failed to send to {f.FailedRecipient}";
                    break;
                case SmtpException s:
                    errorMessage = "Protocol error";
                    break;
                default:
                    errorMessage = "Unexpected error";
                    break;
            }

            //Do anything you want with the error message

            return false;
        }
    }
```

Comment: *Don't* use a callback. `RedirectToAction` creates an ActionResult that should be returned by the action, it doesn't force a redirect. The proper way to do something asynchronously is to use `async/await`. Even if your email library doesn't have task-based asynchronous methods you can adapt it to the task-based model using a TaskCompletionSource. That would be rather unusual though as most libraries have moved from older async models like callbacks, events and APM to tasks

Comment: Looks like you're using SmptClient. The [SendMailAsync](https://learn.microsoft.com/en-us/dotnet/api/system.net.mail.smtpclient.sendmailasync?view=netframework-4.7.2) method is task-based, you could have written `await client.SendMailAsync(email);`. That's an obsolete class though. [The docs themselves](https://learn.microsoft.com/en-us/dotnet/api/system.net.mail.smtpclient?view=netframework-4.7.2#remarks) say it shouldn't be used

Answer (score 4, accepted):

Don't use a callback. RedirectToAction creates an ActionResult that should be returned by the action, it doesn't force a redirect.

The proper way to do something asynchronously is to use async/await. Even if your email library doesn't have task-based asynchronous methods you can adapt it to the task-based model using a TaskCompletionSource. That would be rather unusual though as most libraries have moved from older async models like callbacks, events and APM to tasks.

`MailMessage` suggests you're using [SmtpClient](https://learn.microsoft.com/en-us/dotnet/api/system.net.mail.smtpclient?view=netframework-4.7.2). The [SendMailAsync](https://learn.microsoft.com/en-us/dotnet/api/system.net.mail.smtpclient.sendmailasync?view=netframework-4.7.2) method is task-based, which means you can write

```
await client.SendMailAsync(email);
```

For example :

```
[HttpPost]
public async Task<ActionResult> SendEmail(EmailContentViewModel emailDetails)
{
    SmptClient client = ... //Configure the client here
    using (MailMessage email = new MailMessage(emailDetails.from, emailDetails.to))
    {
        email.Subject = emailDetails.subject;
        email.Body = emailDetails.body;
        email.Priority = emailDetails.MailPriority;

        await client.SendMailAsync(email);
        return RedirectToAction("ContactResult", "Contact", new { success = true }); 
    };
}
```

SmptClient is an obsolete class though. Its documentation page warns that :

> We don't recommend that you use the SmtpClient class for new development. For more information, see SmtpClient shouldn't be used [on GitHub](https://github.com/dotnet/platform-compat/blob/master/docs/DE0005.md).

That link explains that :

> SmtpClient doesn't support many modern protocols. It is compat-only. It's great for one off emails from tools, but doesn't scale to modern requirements of the protocol.

The recommendation is to use newer libraries like [MailKit](https://github.com/jstedfast/MailKit)

MailKit allows explicit casting of a `MailMessage` to a `MimeMessage` which makes it easy to convert the existing code to MailKit:

```
[HttpPost]
public async Task<ActionResult> SendEmail(EmailContentViewModel emailDetails)
{
    var client = new MailKit.Net.Smtp.SmptClient();
    /Configure the client here ...
    using (MailMessage email = new MailMessage(emailDetails.from, emailDetails.to))
    {
        email.Subject = emailDetails.subject;
        email.Body = emailDetails.body;
        email.Priority = emailDetails.MailPriority;

        var msg=(MailKit)email;
        await client.SendAsync(msg);
        return RedirectToAction("ContactResult", "Contact", new { success = true }); 
    };
}
```

**Error Handling**

Both MailKit's and the old SmptClient's Send methods either succeed or throw. One option would be to just hide the exception and return a true/false success flag :

```
try
{
    await client.SendAsync(msg);
    return RedirectToAction("ContactResult", "Contact", new { success = true});
}
catch
{
    return RedirectToAction("ContactResult", "Contact", new { success = false});
}
```

That's not very helpful though, either for the user or the administrator trying to diagnose possible problems. The methods' documentation explains the types of exceptions that may occur, eg: `ArgumentNullException` for a null message, an InvalidOperationException, SmtpFailedRecipientException and more.

At the very least, the code can log the exception before returning failure :

```
catch(Exception ex)
{
    _log.Error(ex);
    return RedirectToAction("ContactResult", "Contact", new { success = false});
}
```

A better idea would be to handle specific exceptions and possibly warn the user :

```
catch(SmtpFailedRecipientException ex)
{
    _log.Error(ex);
    return RedirectToAction("ContactResult", "Contact", new { success = false,message=$"Couldn't send the message to {ex.FailedRecipient}"});
}
catch(SmtpException ex)
{
    _log.Error(ex);
    return RedirectToAction("ContactResult", "Contact", new { success = false,message="Failed to send the message"});
}
catch(Exception ex)
{
    _log.Error(ex);
    return RedirectToAction("ContactResult", "Contact", new { success = false,message="An unexpected error occured"});
}
```

Pattern matching in C# 7 makes this easier :

```
catch(Exception ex)
{
    _log.Error(ex);
    string message="";
    switch (ex)
    {
        case SmtpFailedRecipientException f:
            message=$"Failed to send to {f.FailedRecipient}"; 
            break;
        case SmptException s :
            message="Protocol error";
            break;
        default:
            message="Unexpected error";
            break;
    }
    return RedirectToAction("ContactResult", "Contact", new { success = false,message=message});
}
```

**Separate method**

Refactoring the sending code to a separate method is easy. The try/catch block and the client declaration can be extracted to a separate method :

```
async Task<string> MySendMethod(MailMessage email)
{
    var client = new MailKit.Net.Smtp.SmptClient();
    //Configure the client here ...
    try
    {
        var msg=(MailKit)email;
        await client.SendAsync(msg);
        return "";
    }
    catch(Exception ex)
    {
        _log.Error(ex);
        switch (ex)
        {
            case SmtpFailedRecipientException f:
                return $"Failed to send to {f.FailedRecipient}"; 
            case SmptException s :
                return "Protocol error";
            default:
                return "Unexpected error";
        }
    }
}
```

Instead of returning a `RedirectToActionResult`, the method returns a result string. If that is empty, the operation succeeded. The controller action can be rewritten like this:

```
[HttpPost]
public async Task<ActionResult> SendEmail(EmailContentViewModel emailDetails)
{
    using (MailMessage email = new MailMessage(emailDetails.from, emailDetails.to))
    {
        email.Subject = emailDetails.subject;
        email.Body = emailDetails.body;
        email.Priority = emailDetails.MailPriority;

        var message=await MySendMethod(email);
        return RedirectToAction("ContactResult", "Contact", 
                   new { success = String.IsNullOrWhitespace(result),
                         message=message 
                   }); 
    };
}
```

Comment: Thanks, but your code isn't returning the "result"!

Comment: @Wadjey it is. The `return` is the last statement. The `using` block defines a code block, it's not another function

Comment: @Wadjey as for that "result", what is it supposed to be? If the method succeds, it succeeds. If it doesn't you get an exception. You'll have to explain what you want to return if sending fails

Comment: @Wadjey and as I said, it can only be true or an exception. None of the `Send` methods returns any result.. What do you want to do in case of exception? Just a `try/catch` and return false? Some other message?

Comment: it's a bool in this case to tell if the operation is completed successfully or not, it may be other thing in other cases. How to return such result in your async method? (Please to take a look at my edited code)

Comment: @Wadjey I did. There are no other cases. Sending either succeeds or throws. The way the code is written *hides* the exception. You have to do something with it though. Returning `false` is the easiest thing but doesn't help either the user or you to diagnose the problem

Comment: The idea is to handle the mail sending task in another method (`processSendingEmail`) that manages to send the email and try/catch any exception. The `SendEmail` method should just receive the email sending result (success = true or false) and and act accordingly. _BTW, thanks for all the details and code you're providing._

Comment: @Wadjey first, why? Second, that method should have to do the same things. Use async/await, return a Task<T>, await SendMailAsync, and handle the exceptions. Those exceptions can tell you that the emails couldn't be sent to one or more recipients for example. `true/false` can't tell you that

Comment: @Wadjey once you write the correct sending/error handling code, you can extract it to a separate method. Essentially, it's the entire `try/catch` block

Comment: That's the point, I want `processSendingEmail` to be responsible on any exception related to sending email, it may handle and store the excpetion message in a the database or do anything else... But the `SendEmail` should just know if the email is sent successfully or not by `processSendingEmail` to show a simple message to the user. I want to create two simple methods and each is responsible of it's single specific task. And I still can't figure-out how to do that even with the async/await.

Comment: I already posted that code. Just extract the code to another method, it's a simple refactoring. Just put `async Task<bool> MyMethod(MailMessage email){ ... }` around the try/catch block. Move the SmptClient declaration inside that method

Comment: @Wadjey  I added the refactoring

Answer (score 0):

Use Task base ActionResult intead of callback

```
[HttpPost]
public async Task<ActionResult> SendEmail(EmailContentViewModel emailDetails)
{
   using (MailMessage email = new MailMessage(emailDetails.from, emailDetails.to))
   {
       email.Subject = emailDetails.subject;
       email.Body = emailDetails.body;
       email.Priority = emailDetails.MailPriority;

       var result = await processSendingEmail(email);
       return RedirectToAction("ContactResult", "Contact", new { success = result }); 
   }
}

async Task<bool> processSendingEmail(System.Net.Mail.MailMessage email) {            
    await Task.Delay(1000); //email code here...
    return true;
}
```

Comment: You *assume* that method returns a task.

Comment: The code won't compile here `new { success = result }`

Comment: I have updated the code, You should return result from processSendingEmail function

Comment: The code hasn't changed. `return null` wouldn't be reached whether that function succeeded or not. The question is what's inside that function

Comment: an async method is returning Task, but the `success` is a bool field.

Comment: @Wadjey an async method can return a Task<T> with a result. It doesn't have to be a Task